# Editing a project within another folder

Tags: android, git

Pulling a repository from GitHub on Android Studio, I have some problems. There is the actual app itself with is contained within one folder "myApp". So when cloning the repository on android studio, the program will essentailly have a repository folder that the app is inside of, rather than opening the app itself (which makes sense).

Typically, when you are working on a android project, you open "myApp" folder and directly inside you have .idea - app - gradle folders. But now you are opening the respository folder to get to the myApp folder.

This causes Android studio to not work as well. It can't build a project and you can't add new empty activities because of this. How should i handle this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the project (**File->New->Import project...**), and select **not working folder**. This will get trough your sub-folders, and make it understandable for itself. *Possible grandle and sdk versions needed, but it's not a problem.*

Hope it helps.
Good luck!

Comment: so i originally went through Android Studio and cloned the project to a local repo, AFTER that i can go into that local repo and select the correct folder. THEN after i get done editing can i still commit and push to a BRANCH from inside ANDROID studio? 

I can of course just use git by itself, but i am supposed to use android studio to push to github not git commands

Comment: @JordanFarris if you use the IDE to show the app project as the root, it'll not work with the AS VCS integration. the .git folder wouldn't be present in that folder

Comment: so what is the solution to have that option, while being able to actually use Android studio